# Rails hcaptcha attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha, invisible-recaptcha, hcaptcha

I'm implementing hcaptcha into my rails app, however, one of the attributes has a `-` which rails doesn't play with so wondering about a solution to get past this.

```
<%= f.submit 'Log in', class: "button h-captcha", options: { data-sitekey: "key" } %>
```

The docs require `data-sitekey` to be written like so, however, I get an error, is there any way to keep the `-`?

EDIT:

I've tried the following examples:

```
<div
  class="h-captcha"
  data-sitekey="key"
  data-theme="dark"
  data-size="invisible"
  data-error-callback="onError"
></div>

<%= f.submit 'Log in', class: "button h-captcha", options: { "data-sitekey": "key", "data-callback": "onSubmit" , "data-size": "invisible" } %>
```

rendered the HTML is

```
<div class="h-captcha" data-disable-with="Log in" data-hcaptcha-source-id="input[data-hcaptcha-widget-id='ID']" style="display: none;"></div>

<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Log in" class="button h-captcha" options="{data-sitekey=>key, data-callback=>onSubmit, data-size=>invisible}" data-disable-with="Log in" data-hcaptcha-widget-id="ID">
```

With the second option binding the button I get

```
[hCaptcha] Missing sitekey
```

Using the same keys, but I get an error on one and not the other.

Comment: `...options: { "data-sitekey": "key" } ` ?

Comment: @razvans This is the rendered attribute `options="{"data-sitekey"=>"key"}"` - so I assume this should just work as intended right?

Comment: Yes it should work

Comment: Added an edit @razvans

Comment: has to be:
{ "data-sitekey" => "key" }